# Assets not loading with mod_rewrite with user directories

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite

I am using a Linux based server which handles multiple users allowing each to host their private website. The URL are as follows:

`http://ip.address/~user/website`

To make this work with Cake PHP the following webroot .htaccess was used:

```
1. <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
2.    RewriteEngine On
3.    RewriteBase /~user/Website/app
4.    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
5.    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
6.    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(app/webroot/)?(img|css|js)/(.*)$
7.    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
8. </IfModule>
```

From Cake PHP Cookbook I found the above code for `.htaccess` where line 6 is supposed to provide the directories `img, css, js` access to the real path of the files. However, the above `.htaccess` still results in "Resource not found" for all the files within the above folder.

Comment: What is the actual path of a js/css file?

Comment: @anubhava: its `/system/homes/user/website/app/webroot/js`

Comment: you can try adding this in the `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />` so that every relative URL is resolved from that URL and not the current page's URL.

Comment: @anubhava, that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: OK then I need to see actual HTML sniper how you are including CSS/js etc.